# Azure service for distributed desktop and web application

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

I am trying to figure out which Azure service to use to create a distributed application. The application consists of

- A desktop (Windows) application which is fetching, manipulating and storing data in Azure
- A backend which stores data and does background processing.
- A web front-end which allows me to view the data and trigger background processing in the backend
- Any number of desktop application instances can connect to the backend and access the same data

The desktop application and the web application will send and receive data to the backend. Each message can be up to 100 MB (images etc).

The Azure universe is a bit overwhelming, and I'm trying to find out how to set this up.

My initial thought is to let the desktop application communicate with an Azure Cloud Service with WCF. The cloud service is set up with a WCF web role. A separate web application (web role?) is communicating with the same WCF web role.

The WCF role will also start worker roles to do more heavy, time-consuming processing.

Any ideas and insight is welcome! :)

Comment: This is super-broad and opinion-soliciting. There are so many ways to accomplish this. A great discussion to have, but simply not something for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

For WCF service and web front-end you can use both Azure Cloud Service or App Services - it mostly depends if you need to install some 3rd party components on the machine (Azure Cloud Service allows you to do that).

For background processing use Web Job in App Services or worker role in the Cloud Service. You should also use some queue (I like more Service Bus then Azure Queue from storage account). Your worker role or Web Job should monitor this queue and when you put some message to it then some background processing should be triggered. Background processing could be done also in WCF process itself, but using worker roles or Web Jobs allows you to provide more availability.

For storing blobs (like images) definitely use Microsoft Storage (Blobs), for other data you can use Sql Database or something quite new: DocumentDB. Sql Database is simpler to use and easier to migrate data to other servers etc. but is more expensive.

And of course you can do the same on Virtual Machines, but I guess it wasn't something that you asked for :)

Comment: Thanks! Is WCF the way to go for communication between desktop application and my cloud service, or should I use another technique?

Comment: You have to choices: WCF or WebApi. WebApi is simpler to configure but WCF is much more powerful.

Comment: This is _one_ set of opinions. And your answer is all over the place: You've pinned down cloud service and app service (forgetting virtual machines); you've settled on web jobs or worker roles as background processing (ignoring the ability to do the same thing in already-running web/wcf role instances); you've told the op to *definitely* use blobs for images, and then told the OP that SQL database is "simpler to use" (which I can easily debate, but this isn't the place). And your comment about pricing makes no sense.

Comment: In the part of my sentence "SQL database is simpler to use" I mean what he should consider choosing Sql Database or Document DB (of course I didn't write about all aspects). Blobs in my opinion are definitely the best to store images etc in his project.

Comment: @DavidMakogon please provide better set of services to use in his case instead of criticize.

Comment: @MarcinIwanowski you're missing the point. You can't just list a bunch of services for someone to go exploring, as an answer. And each choice has a lot of researching to understand pro's and con's. This is why these types of questions are off-topic. There's simply no way to answer it objectively.

Comment: I understand your point of view. But in my opinion you are just ignoring a bunch of people who don't know where they should start. We can discuss this during MVP Open Days in Europe or MVP Global Summit.

Comment: Not ignoring  the community at all. Just take a look at my answer history. My point is that StackOverflow isn't set up for discussions/opinions on open ended questions. This is a fantastic discussion to have. On quora, twitter, a blog post, discussion forum. But... not here.

Comment: And if my comments came off as harsh, I apologize for that.

Comment: @MarcinIwanowski I apologize if this question is considered inappropriate for StackOverflow. Which forum would you recommend for this discussion?

Comment: @Jotto I don't see any problem with the question.  It seems appropriate to me.